# change cell imageView in uicollectionview didSelectItemAtIndexPath method

Tags: uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I built a CollectionView controller with fixed imageView in 4 cells.
I'd like the imageView to change on cell selection.
Could you help me with this one?

Thank you

here's my code

CollectionView controller .m

....

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 4;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Cell *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"     forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *image;

    int row = [indexPath row];

    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ICUbedGREEN.png"];

    myCell.imageView.image = image;

    return myCell;
}
```

I'd like the image to change on press but I cannot figure it out...

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ICUbedRED.png"]];

    cell.imageView.image = .....

     NSLog(@"elementselected");
```

}

Answer (score 1):

in your subclass for UICollectionViewCell implement the KVO listening method.  Make sure you set multiselection to true if you want it to be deselected.

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
 if ([keyPath isEqualToString@"selected"])
 {
      // check value of self.selected to know what you are currently.
      // change picture of image here
 }

}
```

in your cells init method you will need to add yourself as a listener so

```
 [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selected" options:nil context:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be most stupid answer to your questions but it worked for me. I dont know how to work with KEy value paths as stated by Samuel.

Basically i made a NSMutableArray to store the status of icons, red or green..YES or NO..

```
selState = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"NO",@"NO",@"NO",@"NO",nil ];
```

and then in "ItemForIndexPath" method, checked the value to set image for that item

```
if ([[selState objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ICUbedGREEN.png"];
}
else
{
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ICUbedRED.jpg"];
}
```

When item is selected, using IndexPath, altered the value of NO into YES or vice versa..

```
if ([[selState objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {
    [selState replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"YES"];
}
else if ([[selState objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
    [selState replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"NO"];
}
```

And then updated the collection View

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

ALL CODE HERE

```
@interface ViewController (){
NSMutableArray *selState;
}
@end
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    selState = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"NO",@"NO",@"NO",@"NO",nil ];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 4;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Cell *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *image;


    if ([[selState objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ICUbedGREEN.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ICUbedRED.jpg"];
    }


    myCell.imageView.image = image;

    return myCell;
}
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:        (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[selState objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {
        [selState replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"YES"];
    }
    else if ([[selState objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
        [selState replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"NO"];
    }

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

@end
```

Thanks

**EDITING---->>**

the above code in *ItemForIndexPath* can also be written in

```
image = [[selState objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"NO"] ?
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"ICUbedGREEN.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"ICUbedRED.jpg"];
```

**END EDITING**